# Apply a function into all my active numbers

Tags: function, twilio, massive

We created a function and now We want to apply this to all our active numbers but I couldn't find a way to change this in mass yet.

Is this posible ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options:

1. You can create a [messaging service](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181308-Getting-started-with-Messaging-Services), configure the webhook there, and then add all your senders to it.
2. You could use the [API](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223135027-Configure-a-Twilio-Phone-Number-to-Receive-and-Respond-to-Voice-Calls) or Twilio CLI to write a script that fetches all active numbers and assigns the Function URL to them.

```bash
curl -XPOST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IncomingPhoneNumbers/PNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.json \
    --data-urlencode "VoiceUrl=http://functionURL.com/twilio" \
    --data-urlencode "BundleSid=BUXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
    -u 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token'
```

3. You can use [TwiML Apps](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180928-How-Do-I-Create-a-TwiML-App-) for this.

Comment: thank you so much. I helped me a lot with this.
We found another way pasting the function's url to the webhook of the Messaging Services.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. You're right, messaging services are also a good way for this. I modified the answer above to list it as well.
Feel free to mark this answer as correct via the checkmark button to help others coming here.

Comment: Hi IObert   I tried to mark as resolved but  seems like I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote.